# Can I make a Project folder anywhere I want after using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, django-apps, virtualenvwrapper

After using mkvirtualenv, I get a folder.

~/virtualenvs/first_project

But I was using another folder as the workspace for all my projects. Can I still use that folder?

Could anyone also please give me a comprehensive roundup of steps to setup django using virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your $PROJECT_HOME anywhere you wish. According to the documentation, you can :

- Create a virtualenv and a project in the same time using

  ```
  mkproject [-t template] [virtualenv_options] ENVNAME
  ```
- "Bind" an existing project to an existing virtualenv

  ```
  setvirtualenvproject [virtualenv_path project_path]
  ```

  You will find all the details here :

http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#project-directory-management

Virtualenvwrapper is so easy to work with !